# why this object still exists without it's composed class even tho it's com-positioned

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

i know that in composition the class composed inside, it's object should not exists outside of its class, but in the example below the `Sword` class is composed into the `Unit` class, and i can still create it's object independently without the unit class, like i did in main, how i can prevent for `Sword` object to exists independently?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Sword sword = new Sword();

}
}

class Sword {
private int a;
}


class Unit {
private String s1;
private Sword s;

void setProperty(String s1, Sword s) {
    this.s1 = s1;
    this.s = s;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `Sword` to be accessed by anything else, you can create it as a private internal class

```
class Unit
{
    private String s1;
    private Sword s;

    public Unit(String s1)
    {
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s = new Sword();
    }

    private class Sword
    {
        private int a;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is another way of doing it, because i see people compose classes without making it a subclass?

Comment: If you look at uninstantiable classes like `Math`, they use private constructors to prevent anybody from creating an instance of it (`private Math() {}`).  This also means you can't create an instance of it either, unless you create a method alternate to the constructor that only your class can call

Comment: Just add a note, the point of composition dependency is that the outer object really owns the inner object (the inner is not shared to any other objects).

Comment: @hiwadoski I did a quick test to see if `Unit` could have a private subclass `Key` to give to the sword creation method, but `key instanceof Key` won't work inside sword since it doesn't have access to `Unit.Key`.  There isn't really a good way to lock it down without just having it be a private internal class

Comment: @NghiaBui okay, i appreciate your note.

Comment: hey @phflack what if we create an object of `Sword` inside `Unit` class constructor like this `public Unit() { s=new Sword();}` , will this still be composition.

Comment: @hiwadoski That's actually how I originally envisioned it, I just derped and misread `void setProperty` as `public Unit` somehow, I copy and pasted your code and completely expected it to be the constructor

Comment: @phflack aha okay, got you.